# curved road detection in satellite images matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, satellite-image

My project is to extract the skeleton of the road in an image using matlab. How to remove the green color shades of trees in the image. I tried hough transform for detecting lines. What could be a better method to detect curved roads in image. I am a beginner in matlab. Kindly help me asap..!

Comment: Post an example image?

Comment: I could not post that image since i am new to this site :(

Comment: Be inventive,  post it somewhere online and link to it?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html

These people have provided code for contour detection and it is widely used in the computer vision community. You can use it for detecting curved lines also